# Send command line arguments to specflow tests

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I have a feature files as part of specflow project. The environment in which i need to execute the specflow tests is taken from the parameter mentioned in "appsettings.json".

I want to run a specflow test from command line wherein I would like to have an option to override the parameters in appsettings.json from the command line arguments.

Can this be achieved?

In Hooks.cs file, i am reading the arguments value in BEFORESCENARIO binding.

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void readarguments()
{
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArguments();
}
```

I am not able to get env=QA as a string in the array args

I ran the test using below command from command prompt :

```
dotnet test --filter "TestName1" -- "env=QA"
```

Comment: Which unit test provider are you using?

Comment: Rather than using command line parameters, could you use [TestRunParameters in a .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022#testrunparameters) and specify the .runsettings file on the command line?

Comment: @GregBurghardt NUnit3TestAdapter

Comment: @sbridewell The problem with that is, the parameters would be fixed in the .runsettings file, and each time I need to change the parameters within the .runsettings file, then every time I need to commit the code change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line to be used in git bash--

```bash
dotnet test -- TestRunParameters.Parameter\(name="\""Country"\"", value="\""INDIA"\""\)
```

.runsettings file content --

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="COUNTRY" value="INDIA" />      
    </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

Process to access the parameter value in a test --

```cs
String _country = TestContext.Parameters["COUNTRY"];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test), you should be able to set environment variables using the `--environment` parameter. In your case, it should be:

```
dotnet test --filter "TestName1" --environment "env=QA"
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should be able to access that value in C# anywhere in your SpecFlow test infrastructure with a simple call to `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("env")`. Since the Environment class is static, you can access this from a hook, step definition, or any class in your test project.

While this does not directly address your question (how to pass command line args to SpecFlow) it *does* address your indirect question (how to set the application environment when running tests).

Comment: Were you using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable static class method just because 
--environment "env="QA" was used in command line arguments. Similarly the docs also mention something called [<args>...] as an option for dotnet test command. In such case which static method should be used to read the arguments?

Comment: @MrAutomation: you can pass arbitrary name/value pairs using the `--environment` parameter. This parameter **sets environment variables** so you are not limited here to just the "application environment."

Comment: It does seem like a poorly named parameter, though.

Comment: The parameter named environment may not suit my case because the customer is not liking the parameter name to be as 'environment'. The client wants a generic parameter name '<NAME>'  whose value can be set from command line and can be accessed in code using TestContext.Parameters["NAME"] .

Comment: @MrAutomation: correct. And that's what the `--environment` parameter does. It is a badly named parameter that allows you to set environment variables. It does not set the application environment. You should be able to pass `--environment "NumberOfChickens=325"` and then retrieve that number in C# using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NumberOfChickens")`.

Comment: @MrAutomation, that's great! Post an answer to your own question!  :) To be honest, I've had this sort of conundrum before. I always worked around it differently, though. Nothing wrong with you asking a question and then posting an answer yourself, which you accept.

Comment: I got it after referring to below links  . https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/862#issuecomment-621737720  So the way it needs to be written is:  dotnet test -- TestRunParameters.Parameter\(name="\""Country"\"", value="\""INDIA"\""\)  and the .runsettings file will be in below format.  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
 <TestRunParameters>
  <Parameter name="COUNTRY" value="INDIA" />  
 </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>  In the code these param values can be accessed using   string country = TestContext.Parameters["COUNTRY"])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254195/discussion-between-mr-automation-and-greg-burghardt).